# Sippy Cup installation

Tags: rubygems, sip

Facing problem while installing sippy cup for SIPp.
Have installed ruby, gem for installation. (Resource: [link](http://mojolingo.github.io/sippy_cup/#install-via-gem-production))

**Install Via Gem**

```
GURroot#gem install sippy_cup
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sippy_cup' (>= 0), here is why:
        Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name      
        (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
```

**Install Via Install from repository**

```
GURKES107root#gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
        Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name  
        (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

This can be a possible reason that I am using a terminal(through putty) with filter on the ***network(limited/no download)***. I am using WinScp for transferring of files/setups/binaries.

***Is there any way without using above mentioned commands, say like downloading the tar file and manually installing the same?***

Ruby,Gem version, Gem environment

```
GURroot#**ruby --version**
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]

GURroot#gem --version
2.4.8


GURroot#gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
- RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /root/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /root/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /root/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
   - ruby
   - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /root/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
   - /root/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
    - /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
    - /usr/local/sbin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /sbin
    - /bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /usr/bin
    - /root/bin
    - /sbin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin
```

Comment: which platform you're using to install this ?

Comment: GNU/Linux
and for more info: 'uname -a returns :                                     
Linux GURKES107 2.6.32-279.39.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 15 05:38:26 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux'